# Failure reading parameter 'context' for pagelink

Tags: java, tapestry

hi i've some problem with error:

I try to passed value integer from one page through pagelink anotger page using context .. code looks  something like:

```
public class Contact
{

    @Persist
    @Property
    private Integer nNumb;

    @Property
    private Integer singleRow;
    @Property
    private Integer singleColumn;

    @Persist
    @Property
    private Integer columns [];
    @Persist
    @Property
    private Integer rows [];

    @OnEvent
    Object onSumbit(){
        rows = new Integer[nNumb];
        for (int i = 0; i < nNumb; i++) {
            rows[i] = i++;
        }
        columns = new Integer[nNumb];
        for (int i = 0; i < nNumb; i++) {
            columns[i] = i++;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public Integer getMultiplyValue(){
        return singleRow * singleColumn;
    }
}
```

**Page Contact.tml:**

```
<body>
        <h1>Multiply Table Page 2</h1>
        <p> Submit integer number N (1&lt;=N&lt;=20): </p>

    <t:form t:id="userInput">
        <p>
             <t:label for="nNumb"/>
             <t:textfield t:id="nNumb" t:label="N:  " t:value="nNumb" t:validate="required,min=1,max=20" />
             </p>
             <p>
              <t:submit t:id="calculate" value="create multy table"/>
              </p>
    </t:form>
    <h1>Result:</h1>

    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#aaaaaa">*</td>
            <td bgcolor="#aaaaaa" t:type="loop" t:source="columns" t:value="singleColumn">
                ${singleColumn}
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr t:type="loop" t:source="rows" t:value="singleRow">
                <td bgcolor="#aaaaaa">${singleRow}</td>
                <td t:type="loop" t:source="columns" t:value="singleColumn">
                <a href="#" t:type="PageLink" t:page="product" t:context="${multiplyValue}">*</a>
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

pagelink throws exception on line 34:

```
Render queue error in BeginRender[Contact:pagelink]: Failure reading parameter 'context' of component Contact:pagelink: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException
```

---

```
    32  <td bgcolor="#aaaaaa">${singleRow}</td>
33  <td t:type="loop" t:source="columns" t:value="singleColumn">
34  <a href="#" t:type="PageLink" t:page="product" t:context="${multiplyValue}">*</a>
35  </td>
36  </tr>
```

What is wrong, am i calling correctly the method multiplyValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that context almost always expects the "value" to be property names, not an expression. So you want:

```
t:context="multiplyValue"
```

instead of

```
t:context="${multiplyValue}"
```

I would think it would do the expression and then convert it to a string (which is what usually happens in context parameters?, but then again, there's the error, so maybe not.

**Update:** (from asker of question in the comments) 
*hi! i found out what is problem....problem was in method onSubmit() when i put                                       rows[i]=i++; and columns[i]=i++ this was wrong.... i have to do: rows[i]=i+1; columns[i]= i+1*

I guess I should have read through the code closer :)

Comment: @dusmanka Sounds odd. Is the method being called? If so, does it throw an exception (NPE)?

Comment: hi! i found out what is problem....problem was in method onSubmit()
when i put 
rows[i]=i++; and columns[i]=i++ this was wrong.... 

i have to do: 
rows[i]=i+1; 
columns[i]= i+1;